# ARDUINO Push button won't randomize numbers for me

Tags: arduino

Help me please. When I press down the button Arduino won't randomize any numbers? I cannot find the solution and I hope that you guys can help me.
The project is for a fair my school is hosting every year. If you guys need more information feel free to ask!

```
const int buttonPin = 1;   
const int ledPin = 12;      
int ledState = HIGH;        
int buttonState;            
int lastButtonState = LOW; 
int counter = 0;
int randNumber;

// the following variables are long's because the time, measured in    miliseconds,
// will quickly become a bigger number than can be stored in an int.
long lastDebounceTime = 0;  // the last time the output pin was toggled
long debounceDelay = 50;    // the debounce time; increase if the output flickers


void setup() {
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);

  // set initial LED state
  digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState);
  Serial.begin(1200);
}

void loop() {
   if(counter==0 && buttonState==HIGH){
  randNumber = random(1,7);
  Serial.println(randNumber);
  Serial.println("counter" + counter);
  counter=2;

  }


  int reading = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  if (reading != lastButtonState) {

    lastDebounceTime = millis();
  }

  if ((millis() - lastDebounceTime) > debounceDelay) {
      if (reading != buttonState) {
      buttonState = reading;

      if (buttonState == HIGH) {
        ledState = !ledState;

      }
    }
  }

  // set the LED:
  digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState);

  // save the reading.  Next time through the loop,
  // it'll be the lastButtonState:
  lastButtonState = reading;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your debouncing will never work, since you are resetting the state every time.

Since re-inventing the wheel is useless, I suggest you to use the `Bounce2` library, which handles debouncing for you.

Something like this should work... I also fixed some types (use `byte`s instead of `int`s when you can, since the processor is an 8-bit one).

```
#include <Bounce2.h>

Bounce debouncedButton = Bounce();

const byte buttonPin = 1;   
const byte ledPin = 12;      
byte ledState = HIGH; 
byte randNumber;

byte lastButtonState;

const byte debounceDelay = 50;    // the debounce time; increase if the output flickers

void setup() {
    pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
    pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);

    debouncedButton.attach(buttonPin);
    debouncedButton.interval(debounceDelay);

    // set initial LED state
    digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState);
    Serial.begin(1200);
    lastButtonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);
}

void loop() {
    debouncedButton.update();

    byte buttonState = debouncedButton.read();

    if(counter==0 && buttonState==HIGH){
        randNumber = random(1,7);
        Serial.println(randNumber);
        Serial.println("counter" + counter);
        counter=2;
    }

    if ((lastButtonState != buttonState) && (buttonState == HIGH))
        ledState = !ledState;

    digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState);

    lastButtonState = buttonState;
}
```

Just two more things:

1. Why are you using a 1200 b/s baudrate? Isn't it too low? Usually the lowest used is 9600, but I usually use 115200 (unless the other device doesn't support it)
2. I couldn't understand the `counter` variable usage. The way you used it (and I copied) will prevent random numbers generation since nothing will reset it. If you want to count the number of numbers generated remove the `counter==0` test, write `counter++` instead of `counter=2` and initialize the variable to 0 in the `setup` function

Comment: Thank you very much for answer! it was 9600 and there was´t  counter==0 and so on. I changed them just because i needed to test how it´s work. But Thank you so much! Have a nice day!